# Error when trying to open a file inside a docker with Elixir

Tags: file, docker, elixir

I'm inside a docker, running a test and trying to open a file using [File.open](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#open/2).

This is my test code:

```
upload = %Plug.Upload{
        filename: "funcionarios.csv",
        path: Path.expand("/home/company/code/project/apps/project_web/test/project_2/resolver/funcionarios.csv", __DIR__)
      }
```

This is the error I get:

> ** (File.Error) could not open "/home/company/code/project/apps/project_web/test/project_2/resolver/funcionarios.csv": no such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I run my code inside a container and I was passing the local path not the container path.

Using the [Path.expand](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#expand/1) it converts the path to an absolute one.

The correct code is:

```
upload = %Plug.Upload{
        filename: "funcionarios.csv",
        path: Path.expand("funcionarios.csv", __DIR__)
      }
```

Comment: OMG, you're a genius!